# Pass input to React sibling

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble passing data between two React siblings. I need to have an input component that will receive and pass the input to sibling that will handle the input and perform some logic.

I get to receive the data in the parent, but I cannot seem to get the passing to the sibling to work...

This is the wrapper/parent

```
  const [corpBrandId, setCorpBrandId] = useState("");
  const [secondInput, setSecondInput] = useState("");
  const handleCorpBrandIdChange = ({ target }) => {
    setCorpBrandId(target.value);
  };
  const handleSecondInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    setSecondInput(target.value);
  };
  const handleClick = () => {
    // console.log(corpBrandId);
    // console.log(secondInput);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <InputField
            label="Corporate brand ID "
            onChange={handleCorpBrandIdChange}
            value={corpBrandId}
          />
          <TableConnect corpBrandId={corpBrandId} secondInput={secondInput} />
          <InputField
            label="Second input param"
            onChange={handleSecondInputChange}
            value={secondInput}
          />
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default MainWrapper;
```

And here's the input component:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <input type="text" value={value} name={name} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputField;
```

I've got no working or remotely close code how to receive the data...
This doesn't work in the sibling:

```
        return (
            <div>
                Test
                {props.corpBrandId}
                {props.secondInput}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) what data you're trying to share. You seem to have some state set up for each of your two input values, but each input field maintains and uses its own state. Do you want both inputs to have the same value, so when one changes its value the other changes too?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply! Yes I see that I might have missed to explain, but if you're referring to that I have two input components in the wrapper? It is because in the end, I want to be able to add a few more input fields. These input fields, I want to be able to individually pass to the sibling (last code section), where I will use the input to determine which API and what params to send with the API calls. Does that answer your question?

Comment: What is "The Sibling"?

Comment: That is a react component of it's own, now handling API calls with some other data. But I would really like to get the input from the input component.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks Community, Chris did however point out that I might had missed to define props. Which I had and did, and it is now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment to @Shahar's answer, it sounds like you maybe haven't defined `props` in your `TableConnect` component.  It should look something like this:

```
const TableConnect = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Test
      {props.corpBrandId}
      {props.secondInput}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here's a codesandbox where `TableConnect` is correctly receiving the input from your input fields: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-cloud-wgub8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi Chris, I could define props in my function TableConnect (props) {} and is now read properly! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
export default InputField; 
        return (
            <div>
                Test
                {props.corpBrandInput} //shouldnt it be: corpBrandId
                {props.inputText}  //shouldnt it be: secondInput
            </div>
        );
  }
```

Comment: Hello, 

Yes, you are correct! I get this error below when I try to access the props.corpBrandId and props.inputText though, where TableConnect is my "sibling" component where I want to use the data passed:

ReferenceError: props is not defined
    at TableConnect (https://localhost:9000/__runFrame/bundle.js:784:15) ...